# fehler beim laden des blocks: ungültige(r) parameter: attributes - Gutenberg

Tags: custom-post-types, errors

I'm using the Gutenberg Block "Custom Post Type"
[image]

It worked well for a long time. Now, as soon as I select it and want to select a blogpost, thats already created, that I wanna display here, this message comes: "fehler beim laden des blocks: ungültige(r) parameter: attributes" and it looks like this(2nd picture)[image]

I really don't know what to do. Does anyone have solution? It's very important for me that this probleme is gonna be solved. Thankful for every single answer! <3

Max

Comment: Is this a third-party plugin you installed that provides that block?  You should check with the developer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: the title translates from german into english as "Error loading block: invalid parameter(s): attributes". As Tony mentioned you should share the source of this block, is it from a plugin or did you write it yourself? There's no technical information or code in this question, no block markup, and no JS errors to work with, you'll need to add significantly more technical information to make this question answerable.